# Fazer um merge entre multiplas databases

Tags: mysql, sql-server, merge

Eu tenho um sistema de cantina que realiza vendas em diferentes escolas. Esse sistema só trabalha online, salvando os movimentos das vendas no server da matriz (MS SQL). Para otimizar o sistema, eu gostaria de trabalhar com ele utilizando uma base local, assim ele funcionaria mesmo sem conexão e ele ficaria muito mais rápido.

O terminal de vendas possui 2GB de memória, e um HD SSD de 40GB, instalado o Windows 7.

Agora eu precisava de uma ajuda para escolher uma opção.
Minha primeira opção era de instalar uma instancia do MS SQL express e fazer um merge das tabelas, assim teria todos os dados das unidades escolares, mas nessa opção fico em dúvidas se o PC vai aguentar o SQL.

Outra opção era de instalar o My SQL por ser mais leve e tentar fazer um merge com o MS SQL da sede.

Alguém teria alguma dica?

Answer (score 2):

Sua ideia é interessante, porém o ideal seria que a base local service apensa para leitura.
Seu sistema deve estar preparado para ler localmente e salvar na matriz.

Nesse caso lhe aconselharia uma replicação Transacional da matriz para sua base local. é bem simples.

Comment: Isto não fornece uma resposta à pergunta. Para criticar ou solicitar esclarecimento de um autor, deixe um comentário abaixo da publicação dele - você sempre pode comentar em suas próprias publicações e quando tiver [pontos de reputação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) suficientes você poderá [comentar sobre qualquer publicação](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/56431)

Comment: Não responde diretamente ao titulo da pergunta, mas responde a pergunta em si. Pelo menos no meu entendimento.